# Negation does not work as expected for SPARQL property paths

Tags: sparql, rdf, freebase

According to [SPARQL Property Paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths), negation is expressed with the operator `!`, i.e., `!(a|b|c|d)` means any relations that do not fall into `{a, b, c, d}`.

Based one this definition, I find the following example very counterintuitive.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX : <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/> 

ASK {
:m.0262dl9 
!(:type.object.type|<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>) 
:common.topic
}
```

The above query returns `false` because the only relations from `:m.0262dl9` to `:common.topic` are `:type.object.type` and `<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>`, which are negated. However, if we add `^:type.object.type`, which means the inverse of `:type.object.type` to the negated set, the answer becomes `true`. In other words, we modify

```
!(:type.object.type|<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>)
```

to

```
!(:type.object.type|^:type.object.type|<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>)
```

This is quite weird, since the first query is false entails that the second query must also be false. I am really not sure why the second query returns `true`. Am I misunderstanding the definition of `!` or `^`?

Comment: this looks more like just a bug, I cannot reproduce this with Apache Jena. Which triple store? Or is there some inference in the backend?

Comment: sample query: `prefix : <http://example.org/>

ask {
:a !(a|^a|:type) :A .
}`

Comment: sample data: `@prefix : <http://example.org/> .

:a a :A .
:a :type :A .`

Comment: return false as expected.

Comment: @UninformedUser I am actually using the SPARQL endpoint set up with Virtuoso

Comment: hm, ok. as said, I cannot reproduce the result with Apache Jena but I did use my own sample data and query as you can see and not the Freebase dataset. The negation `!(a|^a|:type)` does nothing more than following a path that is not one of wrapped properties resp. the inverse - in my sample data there is obviously no other path. But, if I add another triple `:A :p :a .` then there is indeed some inverse path not via `a` and it returns `true`. That means, if in your Freebase dataset there is some triple from `:common.topic` to `:m.0262dl9` not via `:type.object.type` it returns `true`

Comment: If that is the case for your data it's not a bug but as expected. This is like the W3C example: `{ ?x !(rdf:type|^rdf:type) ?y }` which will find nodes connected but not by `rdf:type` (either way round)

Comment: @UninformedUser I can understand that if you add `:A :P :a` to your dataset, it will be true to have a path for `!(a|^a|:type)`. However, my case is that there is no path for `!(a|:type)`, but there is a path for `!(a|^a|:type)`, which is not logically sound at all.

Comment: `!(property|^property)` is any property. Once that is in the expression, any other `|` is not going to change it. So

Comment: @AndyS That's perhaps what is happening, but I am not sure how come `!(property|^property)` is any property.  The operator `^` only means the inverse of a property. Basically,  `!(a|^a)` should just mean any property that is neither `a` nor the reverse of `a`.

Comment: Sorry - you're right.  Have you tried with a different SPARQL engine?